# PHP - File path isn't saved to database with file upload

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I have a script to handle image uploads and puts the location of the image in the database. There's two image upload fields, named "logo-image" and "header-image". The only time when things go wrong is when I only select a "logo-image". What happens then is that the image gets uploaded, but the file path isn't saved to the database. The error must be somewhere in the code below. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
if(file_exists($root."/upload/".$_FILES["header-image"]["name"]))
    {
        $filename = explode(".",$_FILES['header-image']['name']);
        $randomnumber = rand(0, 10000);
        $imageName = $filename[0].$randomnumber.".".$filename[1];
    }
    else
    {
        $imageName = $_FILES['header-image']['name'];
    }

    $image = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars("/upload/".$imageName));

    if(file_exists($root."/upload/".$_FILES["logo-image"]["name"]))
    {
        $filename2 = explode(".",$_FILES['logo-image']['name']);
        $randomnumber2 = rand(0, 10000);
        $imageName2 = $filename2[0].$randomnumber2.".".$filename2[1];
    }
    else
    {
        $imageName2 = $_FILES['logo-image']['name'];
    }

    $image2 = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars("/upload/".$imageName2));


 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["logo-image"]["tmp_name"],     "./upload/".$imageName2) && move_uploaded_file($_FILES["header-image"]["tmp_name"],     "./upload/".$imageName)) {
 // save the data to the database
 mysql_query("INSERT verenigingen SET title='$titlename', description='$contentname', url='$urlname', omslag='$image', logo='$image2'")
 or die(mysql_error()); 

 // once saved, redirect back to the view page
 header("Location: verenigingenindex.php"); 
 }
 elseif (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["logo-image"]["tmp_name"], "./upload/".$imageName2) || move_uploaded_file($_FILES["header-image"]["tmp_name"], "./upload/".$imageName)) {
 // save the data to the database
 mysql_query("INSERT verenigingen SET title='$titlename', description='$contentname', url='$urlname', omslag='$image', logo='$image2'")
 or die(mysql_error()); 

 // once saved, redirect back to the view page
 header("Location: verenigingenindex.php"); 
 }
 else {
     // save the data to the database
 mysql_query("INSERT verenigingen SET title='$titlename', description='$contentname', url='$urlname'")
 or die(mysql_error()); 

 // once saved, redirect back to the view page
 header("Location: verenigingenindex.php"); 
 }
```

Comment: Don't do this... random numbers should NEVER be relied upon to keep your files from colliding. You're using a database. Insert a skeleton record into the DB, get its auto_increment ID, then use that **guaranteed unique** number for your on-disk filename.

Comment: You probably need to post more of the code; is a value for `$image` defined in the case when you have the problem?

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). `htmlspecialchars` is pointless when used here.

Comment: i added the complete code